# Issues getting Suricata Docker Workflow in GitHub to build successfully

Tags: github-actions, suricata

The build is getting stuck on step 10/13 which is:

```
COPY suricata.yaml /etc/suricata
```

The build works successfully on my host and others machines. But when constructed in GitHub it errors out at that step and says:

> cannot locate file `suricata.yaml`

Thoughts as to why it is not able to find the file in the GitHub?

I have verified builds work outside of the GitHub instance.
I have attempted to copy the `suricata.yaml` file into the workflow folder in a last ditch effort to solve and that did not work.

```
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Modified 0 rules.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Dropped 0 rules.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Enabled 131 rules for flowbit dependencies.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Creating directory /var/lib/suricata/rules.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Backing up current rules.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Writing rules to /var/lib/suricata/rules/suricata.rules: total: 45227; enabled: 35215; added: 45227; removed 0; modified: 0
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:50 - <Info> -- Writing /var/lib/suricata/rules/classification.config
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:51 - <Info> -- Testing with suricata -T.
11/10/2023 -- 12:18:54 - <Info> -- Done.
Removing intermediate container f8d4ebf027b7
---> cf321d39e5f3
Step 10/13 : COPY suricata.yaml /etc/suricata/
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat suricata.yaml: file does not exist
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Please include your workflow (only the relevant parts) and the error log in your question. Thanks!